# ClamAV finds eicar in chaindata ldb and quarantines file

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, blockchain, ether, security

What would happen if one of the .ldb files from the mist chaindata was deleted, i.e. /Users/yourname/Library/Ethereum/chaindata/060540.ldb was removed.

One of the ClamAV engines found a test virus signature file this Mist chaindata ldb and quarantined the file.[image]

Comment: Also found blocks with "win.trojan.anaphylaxis-1" using clamwin.
you can dig up what it does, but this sounds like a problem. I'm surprised nobody's even posted about this yet. I looked everywhere.

Comment: Other things to note is that some connections from nodes that our clients connect with are getting blocked because our security is classifying the traffic as: MALWARE-CNC Win.Trojan.Gigade.  Goes without saying but, best to make sure your OS and all your apps are up to date and you're behind a Firewall and more.

Answer (score 1):

geth will have problems. It detects the problem and :

```
I0527 11:35:25.870684 eth/downloader/downloader.go:299] Block synchronisation started
E0527 11:35:31.841495 trie/secure_trie.go:74] Unhandled trie error: Missing trie node 18e46f05aa163833130a37389186d81b71e45b2ad327d2a55cebc96707e894b8
E0527 11:35:31.848416 trie/secure_trie.go:74] Unhandled trie error: Missing trie node 4ce0e366caf31be779a2920c52038167d644f2b5dff5ba34068a7a0ac2c0b53d
E0527 11:35:40.056948 trie/secure_trie.go:74] Unhandled trie error: Missing trie node 26aebd1a922b7a2bed073f5d1eb78f75634e184b69308e143e8ee8b3c1066e0d
E0527 11:35:40.059217 trie/secure_trie.go:74] Unhandled trie error: Missing trie node 26aebd1a922b7a2bed073f5d1eb78f75634e184b69308e143e8ee8b3c1066e0d
E0527 11:35:40.060799 core/blockchain.go:1125] Bad block #1556843 (0x4ff5001e9b610e192fa71b1eb874892dcf98bd5e5f2c3693018a6f6a40dcebc0)
E0527 11:35:40.060813 core/blockchain.go:1126]     gas used error (274044 / 204044)
I0527 11:35:40.060886 eth/downloader/downloader.go:278] Synchronisation failed: gas used error (274044 / 204044)
```

Your data is corrupted and it seems it can't recover. Just remove your chaindata and reload it.

If you try to put the missing file again, it will fail. You have to restore a full working chaindata directory.

Comment: True enough.  That's what we did.  Though, I expect this could be troublesome for many people if indeed eicar is buried there or if the AV was giving a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

Avira Pro did also put *some* *.ldb files  from the chaindata directory in quarantaine. 
After adding an exeption rule for *.ldb in AVIRA and recovering the quarantained files I restarded geth, and it started syncing the blockchaine fine.

I informed AVIRA about this probably false positive detection.
Waiting for their reply.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem yesterday with Avira for Mac. It put one .ldb file in quarantine from the chaindata directory. Restored the file, restarted Mist twice, still not syncing.
I started parity in the terminal. That seems to be syncing alright...

Thanks Andreas for informing AVIRA.